# How can I Link a category entry to a Subsite?

Tags: craft3, structure

I have a Structure Section:

- Home

  - Sub 1
  - Sub 2
- About

  - List item
  - List item
- Info

How can I link the «Home»-Entry in a Structured Section to the «Sub 1»-Entry?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% set home = craft.entries.section('pages').one() %}
{% set sub1 = home.getChildren().one() %}
link: <a href="{{ sub1.getUrl() }}">{{ sub.title }}</a>
```